# Get value from textbox in dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, tabletools

I have a dynamically created table that I am using with DataTables and TableTools - it works great except I have an input textbox that I need to get the value out of when clicking a button, but it just gives me the html, e.g.
**`<input size="3" type="text">`**

I have created a DataTables live to try and recreate the issue, but bizarrely the html returned on there gives the value where it doesn't for me (in the html but still, at least I could parse that) - it still doesn't give you the right value though if you change the Quantity - see here http://live.datatables.net/bidetoku/1/

This is how the table is created:

```
var tr = [];

var sorTable = document.getElementById('tblSORS');

for (var i = 0; i < sorresults.length; i++) {

    tr[i] = document.createElement('tr');
    var tdsorID = document.createElement('td');
    var tdCode = document.createElement('td');
    var tdDesc = document.createElement('td');
    var tdClient = document.createElement('td');
    var tdCreated = document.createElement('td');
    var tdQuantity = document.createElement('td');
    var inputQty = document.createElement('input');

    inputQty.type = "text";
    inputQty.value = "1";
    inputQty.size = "3";



    tdsorID.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sorresults[i].selectSingleNode('./itt_scheduleofratesid').nodeTypedValue));
    tdCode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sorresults[i].selectSingleNode('./itt_code').nodeTypedValue));
    tdDesc.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sorresults[i].selectSingleNode('./itt_description').nodeTypedValue));
    tdClient.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sorresults[i].selectSingleNode('./itt_clientcontractid.itt_description').nodeTypedValue));
    tdQuantity.appendChild(inputQty);
    tdCreated.appendChild(document.createTextNode(returnDate(sorresults[i].selectSingleNode('./createdon').nodeTypedValue)));


    tr[i].appendChild(tdsorID);
    tr[i].appendChild(tdCode);
    tr[i].appendChild(tdDesc);
    tr[i].appendChild(tdClient);
    tr[i].appendChild(tdQuantity);
    tr[i].appendChild(tdCreated);

    sorTable.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].appendChild(tr[i]);
}

var sors = $('#tblSORS').DataTable({
    "destroy": true,
    "info": false,
    "lengthChange": true,
    dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    tableTools: {
        "sRowSelect": "multi",
        "aButtons": ""
    }

});

// hide scheduleofratesid column

sors.column(0).visible(false);
```

Any help would be great, been struggling with this for a while now.

Edit: Here is some code that seemed to half do what I wanted but not completely

```
function getQuantity(){

var table = $('#example').dataTable();
var data = table.$('input').serialize();
var oTT = $.fn.dataTable.TableTools.fnGetInstance('example');

var rows = oTT.fnGetSelectedData();

if (rows.length > 0) {
    var selectedRows = oTT.fnGetSelectedIndexes();

    selectedRows.forEach(function (i) {

        alert(document.getElementById('example')
            .rows[i]
            .cells[0]
            .firstChild
            .value
        );

    });
}
}
```

Comment: can you attach a fiddle??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i did - http://live.datatables.net/bidetoku/1/ - thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a jQuery that might help you:

```
        $(".test").each(function () {
            //Example: add a click event for every item that has the class .test
            $(this).click(function (){
                //This will get you the value from the clicked element
                valueOfElement = $(this).val();
            });
        });
```

However you might have to add a common class for all those imputs.

jQuery reference https://api.jquery.com/each/

Try the next code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#simpleButton").click(function(){
                $(".fields").each(function () {
                    value = $(this).val();
                    alert(value);
                });  
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="texts">
        <input type="text" size="25" value="1" class="fields">
        <br/>
        <input type="text" size="25" value="2" class="fields">
        <br/>
        <input type="text" size="25" value="3" class="fields">
        <br/>
        <input type="text" size="25" value="4" class="fields">
        <br/>
        <input type="text" size="25" value="5" class="fields">
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Get the values" id="simpleButton">
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: That works great and I had something similar but I need it to work with fnGetSelectedData() of tabletools - i've edited the code to show what I tried that didn't work